# How to use rewrite rule to achive this?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

How can I write a rewrite rule so that 
**www.domain.com/any_path/.html** to be changed to **www.domain.com/script.php?url=/any_path/.html ?**
This should also be true for any .htm files.

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule . script.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

or

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ script.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Only for HTML:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(htm|html)$ script.php?url=$1.$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Ohh,, that was so simple.. i was trying this : 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) \script.php?url=$1 and wondering why it dint work..

Comment: Sorry one more question.. I wanted it to work only for html and htm file extensions.. Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Answer updated. When you try to create the rules, check the syntax. `\script.php` seems to be bad.

Answer (score 0):

This will enforce the html extension at the end:
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ script.php?url=$1.html

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^.+\.html?$ /script.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

see END flag on last Apache versions.